# Basic equality $E (X_k I_{A_{k-1}})^2 = \sigma^{2}X_k P(A_{k-1})$ in Kolmogorov inequalities proof

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I've been studying Kolmogorov inequalities on Loève's book on probability (and in many others I find the same problem) but I can't figure out the following (simple) equality:

$E (X_k I_{A_{k-1}})^2 = \sigma^{2}X_k P(A_{k-1})$

where $A_{k} = [ max_{1 \le k \le n} |S_k| < \epsilon]$.

The complete discussion can be found in Loève's Probability theory page 247 (4th edition) but I don't think it's necessary.

My problem is why this equality needs to be true?

**Edit: (just to explain what confuses me)**

What confuses me is that on the left hand side we are integrating on $A_{k-1}$ and on the right hand side on $\omega$ and multiplying by the probability of $A_{k-1}$  I could understand that if $X_k$ was a constant function but I haven't seen that for non-constants

Comment: Indeed, I missed the = sign, sorry about that. Then independence saves the day, as explained below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use that, in your context, the r.v. are independent. Furthermore, the r.v. must have expectation equal to 0.

Since $A_k = [\max_{1 \le j \le k} \vert S_j \vert < \epsilon ]$, the random variables $X_k$ and $I_{A_{k-1}}$ are independent. Thus, $X_k^2$ and $I_{A_{k-1}}$ are independent. You can use the Multiplication Theorem of the expectation to obtain:

$$ E(X_k I_{A_{k-1}})^2 = E(X_k ^2  I_{A_{k-1}}) = E(X_k ^2)  E(I_{A_{k-1}}) = \sigma^2 X_k P(A_{k-1})$$

since $\sigma^2 X_k = E(X_k ^2)$ because $EX_k = 0$.